# TinyMCE filemanager plugin with pagination

Tags: tinymce

I've been looking all day for an appropriate free filemanager for TinyMCE, that has pagination enabled.

I have a few thousand files in one folder and it takes for ever to load everything, if I use Responsive file manager.

Ajaxfilemanager is not an option because of some security issues on the server.

Thank you
Gašper